# Advantages of Facebook groups vs. Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook

I would like to get a good comparison of current features of Facebook groups vs. Facebook pages.

To the best of my knowledge, the only advantage of using a Facebook group is that until you reach 5000 members, you can mass massage all of them (something that goes away starting from your 5001 member).

Is there any other advantage of Facebook groups (over pages) that I don't know about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I dug up a few months ago while considering the move from an organization's Group over to a Page:

- Pages have better brand integration (posts/updates would appear to come from the Organization as opposed to individual members on its behalf
- the counter point to this is that you can't directly blast messages to your "followers/members/friends" the same way you can to friends or in a group.  Pages can only send out "Updates" to all their "fans", which is treated a little differently in that it doesn't go directly into a user's Inbox (different tab to click) and tend get ignored more, IMO
- Pages have no cap on member messaging (can only send to 5000 in a Group)
- Pages can be more easily found in a public search engine (more control in SEO)
- stat tracking, and add-on apps for Pages
- social widget integration for Pages (ie. you can put that "Like" badge on your main site to easily integrate back to Facebook)
- Events are handled the same (was an important consideration for my organization)

Here's a good write up for more detail:

http://www.allfacebook.com/2010/02/facebook-groups-pages/

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Facebook Pages Terms of Service](http://www.facebook.com/terms_pages.php)

> 1. Pages are special profiles that may only be used to promote a business or other commercial, political, or charitable organization or endeavor (including non-profit organizations, political campaigns, bands, and celebrities).
> 2. You may only administer a Facebook Page if you are an authorized representative of the subject of the Page.

This is what makes the difference between a Page and a Group. Groups are more for unofficial things (alumni groups, fan clubs, etc) where Pages are for official things (official fan pages, products, etc.)

Pages also act more as a profile on facebook (you can add applications to it) where a group doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Henri.  but functionally - what other advantages does a group have over a page ?

Comment: @Tal: Edited answer